# Java Array use: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 in array of String

Tags: java, arrays

```
while ((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {

                    String[] words = line.split("\\s+");
                    String a=words[0];
                    String b=words[1];
                    String c=words[2];
}
```

while compiling I got error

> `"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 " in "String b=words[1]".`please provide some solution.

Comment: Looks like your line wasn't split in 2 bits, so second part doesn't exist? Add an `if` to check `words`'s size, or learn more about your language.

Answer (score 0):

Numbering for indices starts at `0` in Java. Your `words` array probably only contains 2 elements which is why you get the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` for the 3rd element.

Anyway it would be better, if you could actually provide the input string.

Try:

```
while ((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {

                    String[] words = line.split("\\s+");
                    if(words.length >= 3){
                        String a=words[0];
                        String b=words[1];
                        String c=words[2];
                    }                      
}
```

Comment: After editing it is showing same error in "String b=words[1]".  Actually i am trying to get the third element of a line.

Comment: Well then your words array only contains one element. That's why you should provide the input string, so we can understand better what you're trying to achieve with your regex.

Comment: Input- is of format
 0.000000000  211.152.36.37   75.130.96.12   101
this is a single line of file . I am trying to read the file of this format containg 97178 such line and get the third element of each row.

Comment: What is the third element? 75.130.96.12?

Comment: yes....75.130.96.12 
ok.....thanks ,now it is working.

Comment: Nice! Accepting my answer would be appreciated :)